# The integral values which makes the expression a perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the integral values of m and n for which $64m^2n^2(m^2-n^2)^2+ (m^2 +n^2)^4$ is a perfect square.

I thought of doing it by hit and trial but it didn't turn out to be a wise option. Is there any initial approach that can make things easier?

Comment: For any $m=n$ the expression is a perfect square

Comment: Also if one of $m,n$ is $0$ and the other is anything. -)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a=m^2-n^2,\,b=2mn$. Then our expression which we want to be a perfect square is $16a^2b^2+(a^2+b^2)^2$, or $a^4+18a^2b^2+b^4$. Since 18 is in [OEIS A253200](https://oeis.org/A253200), there are no solutions with positive $a$ and $b$, so the only solutions are those when either of them equal to 0, which in terms of $(m,n)$ translates to the two cases already disclosed in the comments.